# Are there any other endgame analysis tool than Wilhelm?

Tags: endgame, tablebases

Are there any other endgame analysis tool than [Wilhelm](http://chess-database.com/Tablebase-DVDs/Wilhelm-Readme_en.pdf)?

Comment: What do you mean "deal with"?

Comment: http://www.open-aurec.com/wbforum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=53514

Answer (score 1):

Finalgen (http://finalgenchess.ovh/home_ing.php) generates database for positions with kings, one piece each, and any number of pawns. It has it's disadvantages, but it's free.

Answer (score 0):

[Freezer](http://www.freezerchess.com/) is an awesome endgame analysis tool which supports Nalimov tablebases up to 6-men.